# returning a dynamic calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty sure this is the easiest mistake i can ever overlook. had a similar problem once but cant remember how i solved it for the love of god...

```
import random

enemy_hp = 100
player_hp = 100
enemy_hit = random.randint(1, 10)
enemy_meteor = 8
enemy_heal = 3
player_hit = random.randint(1,10)
player_fireball = 5
player_heal = 7

def eHit(enemy_hit):
    player_hp = 100-enemy_hit
    print (player_hp)

eHit(enemy_hit)
```

ok i edited it and its working as intented, but even with that tutorial i struggle with something else.

> How do i save the new value after the calulation so it doesnt always start at 100?

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is. I would rather not guess. Would you care to tell us what problem you are having with the code?

Comment: my bad, quick finger, edit it

Comment: I would think you've misunderstood the nature of functions. `def eHit(enemy_hit)` defines a function that takes an argument named `enemy_hit` instead of using the variable in the larger scope with the same name. Within the function body, the variable named `enemy_hit` will have the value of whatever has been passed into the function. For more information on this, read: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: You need to *call* functions. `print(eHit)` doesn't call the function. Also -- note that the `int` in `enemy_hp = int(100)` is pointless.

Comment: ye the `=int` was an attempt to find a fix for myself. i guess imma re-read that tutorial and comeback if it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have edited the original question, and you are now asking

> How do i save the new value after the calulation so it doesnt always
>   start at 100?

you need to `return` the new value and assign to the `player_hp` variable and move the randomisation of `enemy_hit` so it actually takes a new value before you call `eHit()`, like this

```
import random

enemy_hp = 100
player_hp = 100
enemy_meteor = 8
enemy_heal = 3
player_hit = random.randint(1,10)
player_fireball = 5
player_heal = 7

def eHit(enemy_hit, player_hp):
    player_hp = player_hp - enemy_hit
    return player_hp

while player_hp > 0:
    enemy_hit = random.randint(1, 10)
    player_hp = eHit(enemy_hit, player_hp)
    print (player_hp)
```

I have put a `while player_hp > 0` in there for testing purposes

Thinking about this, I would do it even a little different again, the following code so you can try this yourself:

```
import random


player_hp = 100

def random_hit(start = 1, stop = 10):
    return random.randint(start, stop)

def enemy_hit(player_hp):
    return player_hp - random_hit()

while player_hp > 0:
    player_hp = enemy_hit(player_hp)
    print (player_hp)
```

now you can call `random_hit()` with default, or with changed parameters for "bigger" hits like `random_hit(20, 30)`, you can also call `random_hit()` from other functions, no need to double assign.

And you can take is further, as a hit is a hit, no matter who is hitting who, so no double functions, something like this:

```
import random


player_hp = 100
enemy_hp = 100

def hit(hp, start = 1, stop = 10):
    return hp - random.randint(start, stop)

while player_hp > 0:  ## while loop only for testing purposes
    # for a enemy hitting a player with normal force, call this:
    player_hp = hit(player_hp)
    print (player_hp)

while enemy_hp > 0:  ## while loop only for testing purposes
    # for a player hitting an enemy with extra force, call this:
    enemy_hp = hit(enemy_hp, 10, 20)
    print (enemy_hp)
```

Comment: worked, even added text telling him how much he got hit for and how much hp he still has.  thanks mate, at least youre nice :P

Answer (score 1):

`print(eHit)` is wrong; `eHit` is a function not a variable. You should call it like `print(eHit(somthing))`

Purely based on the names of the variable declarations at the start, I guess you meant `print(eHit(enemy_hit))`

Then you run into the problem that `player_hp` is a local variable, and used before assignment, so now you need to change `eHit()`

```
def eHit(enemy_hit, player_hp):
    player_hp -= enemy_hit
    return player_hp - enemy_hit
```

and your print statement is now

`print(eHit(enemy_hit, player_hp))`

The same goes for other functions you have defined.